# How to connect from client under NetBeans_RPC to server-side under Spring.httpInvoker?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, netbeans-platform

How to connect from client under NetBeans_RPC to server-side under Spring.httpInvoker?

In my dev I`m using Eclipse, can I work with NetBeans_Platform under Eclipse? Maybe some plugins??

Otherwise, can I work with Spring from NetBeans_IDE? Is NetBeans_IDE support Maven?
And the most important thing, what kind of  _best_practics_&_true_java-way in this case?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I`m using NetBeans wsdl-scaffold, it very easy to create all you need